# Getting the correct row in JTable using TableRowSorter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I'm currently using a JTable with a TableRowSorter to implement a search function for the users. Below is my code

```
    tblDutyList = new JTable() {
        @Override
        public java.awt.Component prepareRenderer(
                TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
            java.awt.Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row,
                    col);
            Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, 4);
            if (value.equals("Inactive")) {
                comp.setBackground(Color.white);
                comp.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                if (tblDutyList.isCellSelected(row, col)) {
                    comp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                    comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                } else
                    comp.setBackground(Color.white);
                comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            return comp;
        }
    };

    tblDutyList.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    String dutyId = "0", dutyName = "", dutyDesc = "", dutySectorName = "", dutyStatus = "", dutyRemoveReason = "";

    Duty d = new Duty(Integer.parseInt(dutyId), dutyName, dutyDesc,
            dutySectorName, dutyStatus, dutyRemoveReason);

    ArrayList<Duty> dutyResult = rdc.processRetrieveDuties(d);

    DutyModel dutyModel = new DutyModel(dutyResult);

    tblDutyList.setModel(dutyModel);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(tblDutyList);

    // sorter for search function
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(dutyModel);
    tblDutyList.setRowSorter(sorter);

    // customizing how the table looks
    tblDutyList.setRowHeight(100);
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(2)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(3)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(4)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    tblDutyList.getColumnModel().getColumn(5)
            .setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
```

where the JTable will load all my duties from the database. Afterwhich, the user can select a row from the table and perform some tasks like assign, update, and delete. However, my problem is, when I use the filter function, the user will get the **wrong record**, for example the first duty is "cleaning the windows", and the second one is "sweeping the floor", and I filter out "sweeping the floor" which will then render "sweeping the floor" as the record right on top of the table. The user selects the result ("sweeping the floor") and presses any of the actionPerform, and will be redirected to get "cleaning the windows" instead, since that's originally the first value. This is my a part of actionPerformed code:

```
            if (tblDutyList.getSelectedRow() != -1) {                   
                int rowIndex = tblDutyList.getSelectedRow();
                int idDuty = (int) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                        rowIndex, 0);
                String name = (String) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                        rowIndex, 1);
                String desc = (String) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                        rowIndex, 2);
                String sector = (String) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                        rowIndex, 3);

                String status = (String) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                        rowIndex, 4);
```

This probably means that my actionPerformed will get the value at the specific location instead of reading the values before my user is redirected. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to use one of the `JTable`'s conversion methods...

- [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int))
- [`JTable#convertRowIndexToView(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView(int))

This will allow you to convert between what the view and model thinks the row value means, for example...

```
int rowIndex = tblDutyList.getSelectedRow();
rowIndex = tblDutyList.convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex);
int idDuty = (int) tblDutyList.getModel().getValueAt(
                    rowIndex, 0);
```

Take a closer look at

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

For more details...

Comment: it works! thank you so much i hope you will have a wonderful day ahead <3

Answer (score 2):

From the docs. (which you should read) for [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)..

> Similarly when using the sorting and filtering functionality provided by `RowSorter` the underlying `TableModel` does not need to know how to do sorting, rather `RowSorter` will handle it. Coordinate conversions will be necessary when using the row based methods of `JTable` with the underlying `TableModel`. All of `JTables` row based methods are in terms of the `RowSorter`, which is not necessarily the same as that of the underlying `TableModel`. For example, the selection is always in terms of `JTable` so that when using `RowSorter` you will need to convert using `convertRowIndexToView` or `convertRowIndexToModel`. ..

Comment: I'm wondering if we should propose a "should have read the docs/tutorial" close option...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've typed it in a few times as a custom close reason (which I was tempted to do this time as well).  I figure we have a better case for introducing it if it commonly appears as a custom close reason..